# "in a measure for the bustle and blare and intrigue" - meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Reading another story from C.A. Smith, I have been trying to figure out the following sentence, to no avail:

> It consoled him **in a measure for the bustle and blare and intrigue** of
> the imperial court, where he held an official post of no small honor;
> since he was not altogether native to such things and would have
> preferred, like the olden sages, the philosophic peace of a
> leaf-embowered hermitage.

I understand most of it, but not the first part marked in bold. What does it exactly mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“It consoled him in a measure” means that it partially consoled him (it’s a rather old-fashioned and uncommon construction that you wouldn’t expect to see in contemporary English, but that doesn’t make it wrong). The “bustle and blare and intrigue” are the unpleasant things for which he needs consolation.

It would be easier to read and parse with a couple of commas: “It consoled him, in a measure, for the bustle and blare and intrigue of the imperial court”.

Comment: A more contemporary equivalent to antiquated ***in some measure*** here would be ***to some extent***.